# Do I have to buy minecraft twice

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Do I have to buy minecraft to get a new account on a PC that already has minecraft installed? I am teetering on and off on this question. Searched the web probably 1,000,000,000 times but can't find this specific question's answers.

Comment: It doesn't matter if Minecraft is already installed; you need your own account to play it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not buying Minecraft.  You are buying an account.  So yes, you have to pay again if you want a second account.